# Checking internet connection in 2nd thread in kivymd app

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

so, I have app in kivy/kivymd- it contains 2 windows, 1st window runs in infinity loop looking for input, but I want it to check form time to time whether or not it has internet connection - probably in 2nd thread.

KV settings:

```
KV = """
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: "MainWindow"
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: self.background
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    BoxLayout:
        id: layout
        orientation: "vertical"
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
        
        Label:
            text: ''
            font_size: 1
        
        Image:
            source: 'logo.jpg'
            allow_stretch: True
            size_hint_y: None
            width: 80   

        Label:
            id: info
            text_size: self.size
            text: 'scan here'
            font_size: 26
            size_hint_y: None
            text_size: self.width, None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            halign: 'center'

        Label:
            id: clock
            text: ''
            font_size: 60

        TextInput:
            id: kod
            text: ''
            multiline: False
            size_hint: (0, .5)
            font_size: 15
            
            #opacity: 0
            focus: True
            password: True
            text_validate_unfocus: False
            on_text_validate: root.update_label(kod.text)

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: 'button1'
            icon_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.5
            pos_hint: {"x":0.35, "top":1}
            on_release: 
                app.root.current = "SecondWindow"
            
        Label:
            id: wifi
            text: ''
            font_size: 5
        
        Label:
            text: 'gui apk'

<SecondWindow>
    name: "SecondWindow"

    MDBoxLayout:
        id: layout
        orientation: "vertical"
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
        md_bg_color: 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0
        
        Label:
            text: 'log in'
            font_size: 22

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: 'button1'
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.5
            pos_hint: {"x":0.35, "top":1}
            on_release: 
                app.show_date_picker()
                
        MDRaisedButton:
            text: 'exit'
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.5
            pos_hint: {"x":0.35, "top":1}

            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "MainWindow"
                root.manager.get_screen("MainWindow").ids["kod"].focus = True

        Label:
            text: 'gui apk'
        
"""
```

Code:

```
import fdb
import configparser
import threading
import time
import socket

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import mainthread
from kivymd.uix.pickers import MDDatePicker




config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(r'C:\\Users\\Przemek\\Desktop\\RCP\\config.txt')   

RED_BACKGROUND = [.75, 0, 0, 1.0]
BLACK_BACKGROUND = [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0]
GREEN_BACKGROUND = [0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 1]
BLUE_BACKGROUND = [0, 0, 1, 1]

class MainWindow(Screen):
    background = ListProperty()
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.background = BLACK_BACKGROUND
        Clock.schedule_interval( self.UpdateClock, 1 )
        threading.Thread().start()
        
    @mainthread
    def update_label(self, val):
        
        con = fdb.connect(
        port = int(config.get('global', 'port')),
        database = str(config.get('global', 'database')),
        host = str(config.get('global', 'host')),
        user = str(config.get('global', 'user')), 
        password = str(config.get('global', 'password')),
        charset = str(config.get('global', 'charset'))
        )
        cur = con.cursor()
             
        cur.execute("select KOD, FK_KRT_PRC, ID FROM TABLE")
        if len(val) > 0:
            print('main loop here')
        con.commit()
        con.close()
        self.ids.kod.text = ''
                
    def SetStartScreen( self, dt ):
        self.ids.info.text = 'scan'
        self.background = BLACK_BACKGROUND
        
    def UpdateClock( self, dt ):
        self.ids.clock.text = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

        
class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MyMainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "gui apk"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_save(self, instance, value, date_range):
        print(instance, value, date_range)
        pass

    def on_cancel(self, instance, value):
        pass

    def show_date_picker(self):
        date_dialog = MDDatePicker(mode="range")
        date_dialog.bind(on_save=self.on_save, on_cancel=self.on_cancel)
        date_dialog.open()

       
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

My function to test internet connection

```
    def check_connection():
        try:
            host = socket.gethostbyname('www.google.com')
            s = socket.create_connection((host, 80), 2)
            #print(True)
            return True
        except:
            return False
    res = check_connection()
    print(res)
```

I try to put check_connection and call it in various places but w/o success

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Is the problem that your `check_connection()` does not return the desired result? Or are you unsure of how to call that method in a 2nd thread?

Comment: yup, I couldn't figure out where shall I put this function and from where call it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the code below.  One thing I noticed in your question is the line threading.Thread().start(); this will not do anything because no function was submitted as the target of the thread.

```
import socket
import time
from threading import Thread, Event


def check_connection(internet_on: Event, interval: float = 60.0) -> None:
    print("starting function intended to be in a new thread")
    internet_on.clear()
    # one could also import Queue from queue and return specific error
    # messages by putting them in the queue in this thread and checking
    # for them in the main thread.
    while True:
        try:
            _host = socket.gethostbyname('www.google.com')
            s = socket.create_connection((_host, 80), 2)
        except socket.gaierror:
            internet_on.clear()
        except Exception as e:
            internet_on.clear()
        else:
            internet_on.set()
        time.sleep(interval)


_internet = Event()

# set daemon to True so the thread automatically closes when your main program ends
new_thread = Thread(target=check_connection, args=(_internet, 5.0), daemon=True)
new_thread.start()

# below is just an example so this code will execute
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print(f"internet on = {_internet.is_set()}")
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'll test this later, when I'll have more free time, but in before, where do I put this function, in MyMainApp?

Comment: yes, you can do this in __init__ or the build() method of the App.  you may need to pass the variable _internet into a widget, depending where you want to access it.  you may need to create it as self._internet = Event() instead of _internet=Event() if you want to access it anywhere within your App object.